# Load .txt file with pickle on non GPU machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, pytorch, loaddata

I am trying to load a .txt file on a **non** GPU machine. The .txt file was dumped on a GPU machine:

```
with open("Data/all_rewards.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(all_rewards, f)
```

The file contains just text data, no network models or anything else.
On a GPU machine, I have no trouble loading the data:

```
with open("all_rewards.txt", 'rb') as f:
    losses = pickle.load(f)
```

On a **non** GPU machine however, I get the error:

```
AssertionError('Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled',)
```

Since Torch uses pickle too to load models, I have tried to load the data with :

```
losses = torch.load("all_rewards.txt", map_location='cpu')
```

but that didn´t work.
Could you help me plaese?

EDIT:
Somehow this problem solved itself magically. I have reinstalled pickle, which did not solve the problem initially but now it works...

Comment: I am involved in exactly the same issue.  I have a pickle file that dumped from GPU 2 and i want to load it to GPU 0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the way you have installed `pytorch` on your non-gpu machine. You need to run a command in addition to `pip install torchvision`

If you head to https://pytorch.org/ and select CUDA: `None` with your OS configuration you should receive an additional http link to download an additional wheel package.

For example: Linux, pip and Python3.6 results in the following additional command

`pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not bring any solution to my problem. Pickle just won´t let me load the data. Is it possible to use pickle without torch?